# Loading CSS Style Dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a style-sheet that is saved in this location:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/core/styles/Style.css
```

Now, what I need to do is load it using that full directory, because the files that are going to be using it are located here:

```
/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/client/
```

My goal is to create a completely dynamic site that updates correctly to numerous "Clients" based on their own personal information. So far I've got everything done, however I wanted to move the CSS to be loaded dynamically as-well so if I wanted to make any changes to the style-sheet they would be instantly noticed.. Here's where I'm running into a problem, I can't figure it out. I've followed the front page of google to a dozen of different methods using JavaScript, but none of them have worked and they are all from 2009-2010.. Perhaps someone would like to shed some light on my dark path?

Comment: have you tried $.get http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: `var cssLink = $("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='"PERSONAL_CSS.css"'>"); $("head").append(cssLink); ` Put it in a function and you're good to go.

Comment: What is the root of the web-server, `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`, or are you using virtual hosts for your clients?

Comment: @jeroen - /opt/lampp/htdocs/ is the root

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

`document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/opt/lampp/htdocs/project/core/styles/Style.css" media="screen" />');`

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant document - assumed 'document' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/eDash/index.php on line 2

Fatal error: Call to undefined function write() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/eDash/index.php on line 2

Comment: You have to use this code snipped in the frontend it's JavaScript not PHP

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to use javascript unless a loaded page needs to refresh automatically when the style-sheet is changed.

If you just need it to reload automatically on the next page-load, you can use something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/project/core/styles/Style.css?v=<?php echo time(); ?>">
```

Using an absolute path makes sure it will work for any client / file in any folder.

I have added the timestamp to the css file so that it will not be cached but you can also set up the server to disable caching for specific files.